# add unique class in randomly position to the div with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I need all divs with the class "nprotagonistas__bg" only one add the class "hover" randomly.

```
<div class="nprotas">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="nprotagonistas">
                <div class="nprotagonistas__bg grey">
                </div>
                <div class="nprotagonistas__content lectores">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="nprotagonistas">
                <div class="nprotagonistas__bg white">
                </div>
                <div class="nprotagonistas__content controladores">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="nprotagonistas">
                <div class="nprotagonistas__bg black">
                </div>
                <div class="nprotagonistas__content videointercomunicacion">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="nprotagonistas">
                <div class="nprotagonistas__bg red">
                </div>
                <div class="nprotagonistas__content aplicacion">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That is, only one of the class "nprotagonistas__bg" has to have the class "hover" randomly.

Comment: when should this happen, after a button click or page loaded or maybe when it's hovered ?

Comment: Do you run it on a server or do you expect this change to take place in the browser? If you run it on a server, what language do you use?

Comment: @ths only need add class "hover" randomly in one of "nprotagonistas__bg"

Comment: @AlexL Is a static web

Comment: @LuisPaico and that happens when the page loads a random div gets the hover class ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: @ths yes,  when the page loads

Comment: @LuisPaico I just added an answer, check it out !

Comment: @ths thank you very much, but added the class "hover" more than once. I just need to be added once. 

Comment: @LuisPaico please comment on my answer. No it only add the class once  and to only one div on the page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understood what you really want, but, here's a solution to achieve your task when the page is loaded.

So, when the page is loaded, we fetch all the `div`s containing the class `nprotagonistas__bg` and then randomly we'll assign the class `hover` to only one of the `div`s. This will be done depending on the **number** of `div`s containing the class `nprotagonistas__bg` and we'll use the built-in `random` method to get a random number that will be used as the index of the selected `div`(the random number is the index on the page of the `div` that's selected to get the `hover` class, so reloading the page ends in getting another random `div`).

With all that being said, here's a snippet to illustrate:

> In the snippet, the `hover`class adds a red `background` to the element that has this class.

```js
// waiting till the page is loaded by listening to the 'load' event on the 'window' object.
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  /**
  * fetch all the divs with the class 'nprotagonistas__bg'.
  * getting the number of these divs on the page(how many div is there).
  * using the 'random' method we'll get a random number that is >= 0 and <= the number of the divs.
  **/
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.nprotagonistas__bg'),
      l = divs.length,
      r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * l) - 1;
  // assign the 'hover' class to a div depending on thethe random number.
  divs[r].classList.add('hover');
});
```

```css
.nprotagonistas__bg {
  /* just to make the divs visible on the page */
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.nprotagonistas__bg.hover{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nprotas">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="nprotagonistas">
                <div class="nprotagonistas__bg grey">
                </div>
                <div class="nprotagonistas__content lectores">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="nprotagonistas">
                <div class="nprotagonistas__bg white">
                </div>
                <div class="nprotagonistas__content controladores">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="nprotagonistas">
                <div class="nprotagonistas__bg black">
                </div>
                <div class="nprotagonistas__content videointercomunicacion">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="nprotagonistas">
                <div class="nprotagonistas__bg red">
                </div>
                <div class="nprotagonistas__content aplicacion">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/random) about the `random` method.
>
> [Learn more](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/ceil) about the `ceil` method.
>
> [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) about the `addEventListener` method.

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: thank you very much, but added the class "hover" more than once. I just need to be added once.  Check: [link](https://i.imgur.com/km2IQvt.png)

Comment: @LuisPaico Do you add the `hover` class manually on the `HTML`(using your editor) ?

Comment: execute this line `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.hover').length)`  in your navigator's console and you'll see that my script add the class to only one div !

Comment: ok, it was my problem.

The html was loading twice my .js file

Thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".nprotagonistas__bg");
    var numberOfElements = elements.length;
    var randomIndex =  Math.floor(Math.random()*numberOfElements) + 1;

    var current = elements[randomIndex];
    current.classList.add('hover');
    /* console.log('test'); */

});
```

You can improve it by triggering it when some event happened on your website like a click, a mouse hover, and so on and so though.

and to be sure that the `.hover` class is only on one element after the event is trigger because that event can be triggered many time

for example a click event on the body, within the event handler you select all the `.nprotagonistas_bg` and remove the `hover`

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".nprotagonistas__bg");
elements.foreEach(function(element){
    element.classList.remove('hover')
});
```

after that you can generate again a randomIndex and add the `hover` class to the corresponding element

Comment: thank you very much, but added the class "hover" more than once & never select the first. I just need to be added once. 

Comment: You want to attach the hover class randomly to one element or only to the first element? The code put the hover class only to one element